# How do I from a JSON object convert to form of elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JSON object as `{a: 1, b: 2, c: [4, 5, 6], d: {x: 7, y: 8, z: [9, 0]}}`, how do I convert it to a form of elements?

I want to convert to this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="obj[a]" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="obj[b]" value="2"/>
<input type="hidden" name="obj[c][]" value="4"/>
<input type="hidden" name="obj[c][]" value="5"/>
<input type="hidden" name="obj[c][]" value="6"/>
<input type="hidden" name="obj[d][x]" value="7"/>
<input type="hidden" name="obj[d][y]" value="8"/>
<input type="hidden" name="obj[d][z][]" value="9"/>
<input type="hidden" name="obj[d][z][]" value="0"/>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: may be have a jquery-plugin can do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These should do it:

### *with jQuery*

```
var obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: [4, 5, 6], d: { x: 7, y: 8, z: [9, 0] } };

function analyzer(o, trail) {
    if (!trail) trail = 'obj';
    for (var n in o) {
        var el = $('<input>', { type: 'hidden' });
        el.attr('name', trail + '[' + n + ']');
        if (typeof o[n] === 'number') {
            el.attr('value', o[n]);
            $('body').append(el);
        } else if (Array.isArray(o[n])) {
            el.attr('name',function(i,v) { return v + '[]'; });
            for (var i = 0; i < o[n].length; ++i) {
                el.clone().attr('value', o[n][i] ).appendTo('body');
            }
        } else {
            analyzer(o[n], trail + '[' + n + ']');
        }
    }
}
analyzer(obj);
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aNC8W/)**

FYI, you can find a compatibility patch for `Array.isArray` at MDN.

Or you can use `jQuery.isArray()` instead.

---

### *jQuery reworked*

You may prefer this a bit. It doesn't create an element, then clone it in the Array loop, but rather uses a little redundant code to create the elements.

```
function analyzer(o, trail) {
    if (!trail) trail = 'obj';
    for (var n in o) {
        if (typeof o[n] === 'number') {
            $('<input>', { type: 'hidden', name: trail + '[' + n + ']', value: o[n] })
                .appendTo( 'body' );
        } else if (Array.isArray(o[n])) {
            for (var i = 0; i < o[n].length; ++i) {
                $('<input>', { type: 'hidden', name: trail + '[' + n + '][]', value: o[n][i] })
                    .appendTo( 'body' );
            }
        } else {
            analyzer(o[n], trail + '[' + n + ']');
        }
    }
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aNC8W/2/)**

---

### *with native DOM API*

If you're having any performance issues, use the native API, and cache the DOM selection.

```
function analyzer(o, trail) {
    var el;
    if (!trail) trail = 'obj';
    for (var n in o) {
        if (typeof o[n] === 'number') {
            el = document.createElement('input');
            el.type = 'hidden';
            el.name = trail + '[' + n + ']';
            el.value = o[n];
            container.appendChild( el );
        } else if (Array.isArray(o[n])) {
            for (var i = 0; i < o[n].length; ++i) {
                el = document.createElement('input');
                el.type = 'hidden';
                el.name = trail + '[' + n + '][]';
                el.value = o[n][i];
                container.appendChild( el );
            }
        } else {
            analyzer(o[n], trail + '[' + n + ']');
        }
    }
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aNC8W/3/)**

Doesn't require much more code, should work in all typically supported browsers, and should be very fast.

---

### *native API reworked to shorten*

```
function analyzer(o, trail) {
    var el;
    if (!trail) trail = 'obj';
    for (var n in o) {
        (el = document.createElement('input')).type = 'hidden';
        el.name = trail + '[' + n + ']';
        if (typeof o[n] === 'number') {
            container.appendChild( el ).value = o[n];
        } else if (Array.isArray(o[n])) {
            el.name += '[]';
            for (var i = 0; i < o[n].length; ++i) {
                container.appendChild( el.cloneNode(false) ).value = o[n][i];
            }
        } else {
            analyzer(o[n], trail + '[' + n + ']');
        }
    }
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aNC8W/5/)**

Comment: Wow is working but may be a bit slowly, I'm testing now, back soon. Thanks.

Comment: @joe: Let me know how it goes. It should be pretty quick, but we can speed things up if we use some native API calls in place of jQuery.

Comment: That is really great, is my mistake, I like it very much, thank you++

Comment: @joe: You're welcome. FYI, I just added a third solution using only native API.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick response -

Create a function that loops through objects. Use a `for in` loop to create a string to concatonate these inputs. Test if the value found for each object contains a `primitive value`, `array` or object`.

E.g.
`Object.prototype.toString.call(val) === '[object Object]';`

If it does, recursively call the function to extract the values from said found `object` / `array`

Comment: Add [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) for the first part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here this does not give the code for creating the HTML, but what it does it create an object with two arrays.  One contains the name and the other contains the value.  Also, this will work no matter how deeply you nest your objects.

```
Array.prototype.isArray=true;//Not sure this is the best solution, but it seems to work

function parse(a){
  var b,c,i,obj={
    name:[],
    value:[]
  };
  for(x in a){
    b=a[x];
    if(b.isArray){
      for(i=0;i<b.length;i++){
        obj.name.push('['+x+'][]');
        obj.value.push(b[i]);
      }
    }
    else if(typeof b==='object'){
      var f=x;
      var d=parse(b);
      for(i=0;i<d.name.length;i++){
        d.name[i]='['+f+']'+d.name[i];
      }
      console.log(d.name);
      obj.name.push.apply(obj.name, d.name);
      obj.value.push.apply(obj.value, d.value);
    }
    else{
      obj.name.push('['+x+']');
      obj.value.push(b);
    }
  }
  return obj;
}
console.log(parse({a: 1, b: 2, c: [4, 5, 6], d: {x: 7, y: 8, z: [9, 0]}}));
```

Comment: I was about to ask how `b.isArray` would work, but then I saw your `Array.prototype` extension. Seems like a valid approach to me.